# copy, retain and reference count in NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, copy, retain, retaincount

What does actually mean when I use copy, retain with NSString properties and assign it to local variables?

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject 
{ 
   NSString *name; 
   NSString *name2;
} 

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name1;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name2;
```

If I assign the value of string to another NSString variable like:

```
NSString *newString1 = name1;
NSString *newString2 = name2;
```

what will be retain count of name1 and name2?

```
NSString *anotherString1 = [NSString alloc]initWithString:name1];
NSString *anotherString2 = [NSString alloc]initWithString:name2];
```

what will be the retain count of name1 and name2 here?

Comment: Don't concern yourself with the retain counts of objects, just concern yourself with ownership. If you own it, you must release it later. If you don't own it, you don't release it.

Answer (score 6):

When you allocate an object, its retain count begins at 1. Every time you retain, it goes up by one, and every time you release, it goes down by one. The other factor here is autorelease. When an object is autoreleased in the context of an autorelease pool, its retain count will automatically go down by one when the autorelease pool is drained.

In your examples, for the first one, `name1` and `newString1` will both be pointers to the *same* object, with that object's retain count staying the same. It would only go up if you explicitly call retain. Same with `name2` and `newString2`. In the second example, you are allocating a *new* instance of an NSString object, so the new ones, `anotherString1` and `anotherString2` would have retain counts of 1. `name1` and `name2` would stay the same, again, because you didn't release or retain them.

Your second example is essentially the same as `copy`. While `retain` simply increments the retain count of an object, `copy` creates a new one one with its own retain count. The related thing to flag here is in your declaration of `name1` and `name2` as properties. If you set those properties, they will behave as I'm describing here with `name1` retaining the `NSString` you set there and `name2` copying it as a new object.

Another good overview of all this is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MemoryManagement.html), with a link to an even more [detailed discussion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i) at the bottom.

This all being said, in OS X, you can use garbage collection, and on iOS 5, [automatic reference counting](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html). These can significantly reduce, if not eliminate, your need to worry about this stuff.

Comment: what will be the retain count of newstring1 and newstring2 if i use newstring2 = [newstring1 retain] and what will be retain count if i use newstring2 = [newstring1 copy]

Comment: The first `newstring2` would be the *same object* as `newstring1` and have a retain count of one more than it had (`retain` returns the object it retains). In the second example, `newstring2` would be a copy of `newstring1`, but they would be *different objects*, `newstring1`'s retain count not having changed, and `newstring2` having a retain count of 1, because it was just initialized.